# Passing item in Model to partial view not working ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an array of items in my view and am trying to iterate over that array and pass each item to a partial view, however it throws an exception saying that I'm trying to pass the entire array rather than just the single item to the partial view.

My main view:

```
@model Product[]
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  @Html.Partial("_ProductDetail", item)
}
```

My partial view:

```
@model Product
<div>
  @Model.Description
</div>
```

The exception message:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Product[]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Product'.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**
The controller is definitely passing an array, here's the code though:

```
public ActionResult Category(string id)
{
  var model = FakeDb.Products;
  return View(model);
}
```

And the FakeDb:

```
public static class FakeDb
{
    public static Product[] Products { get; set; }

    static FakeDb()
    {
        Products = new Product[2];
        DateTime utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;

        ProductPic pp1 = new ProductPic { Filename = "71b.jpg", Default = true };
        Product p1 = new Product { DateAdded = utcNow, Price = 395, Quantity = 1, Pics = new List<ProductPic> { pp1 }, Description = "5 ft. x 8 ft. Blue, Yellow" };
        Products[0] = p1;

        ProductPic pp2 = new ProductPic { Filename = "72b.jpg" };
        Product p2 = new Product { DateAdded = utcNow.AddDays(-1), Quantity = 2, Pics = new List<ProductPic> { pp2 }, Description = "5 ft. x 8 ft. Blue, Green" };
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you provide the code in the controller passing the model to the view? Markup looks fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When an element passed to `Partial` is null, it will pass parent view `Model` instead. So if element in `Product[]` array is null, parent's view model will be passed to `Partial`.

You could possibly check if any element in array you're iterating over is not `null` or pass `@Html.Partial("_ProductDetail", new ViewDataDictionary(item))`.

**Foreach approach:**

```
@model Product[]
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    if (item != null)
    {
        @Html.Partial("_ProductDetail", item)
    }
}
```

**ViewDataDictionary** approach:

```
@Html.Partial("_ProductDetail", new ViewDataDictionary(item))
```

Comment: Ah, found it. Forgot to add the second product to the array in my FakeDb. Thanks!